# Unable to apply data patch Magento\GroupedProductSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallGroupedProductSampleData

Tags: adobe, magento2

while type the php bin/magento setup:upgrade the terminal when occur error at 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData'

Error Image

[image: 1]